# Use Build phase to validate XML (Maven)

Tags: java, xml, maven, netbeans, xsd

I would like to validate my XML files against the XSD i have written during the project Build, and if the XML is not valid the build should not complete.

Is the possible? if so can you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a Great Solution ([xml-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/)). 
This is a Maven plugin that validates xml vs schemas, and more

Comment: +1 but you sould have mentioned that the question was about Maven build

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a script as a pre-build event, then you can call validation code that checks your XML against your XSD.

I don't work in NetBeans but I found this menu option with a Google search:

`Project Properties -> Build -> Make -> Build Command`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely possible and a good idea.  All you need is a validating XML parser.  These are available in many languages including Java, .Net, etc.